# Searching contact in Outlook by UserID

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

What I want to achieve is to find a contact in Outlook by a UserID. Here's the peek into the code I'm using (pulled together using hints from other threads on this forum):

```
Sub Lookup_address_book (a as Integer, thissheet as Worksheet, myrange as Range)

Dim myoutapp as Object
Dim myNameSpace as NameSpace
Dim myAddrList as AddressList
Dim myAddrEntry as AddressEntry
Dim alias as String
Dim cell as Range

Set myoutapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Appliation")
Set myNameSpace = myoutapp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set myAddrList = myNameSpace.AddressLists("All Users")

With thissheet

For Each cell In myrange
alias = .Cells(cell.row,a)
Set myAddrEntry = myAddrList.AddressEntries(alias)
.Cells(cell.row,a+1) = myAddrEntry.Name
.Cells(cell.row,a+1) = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser.Department
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Well, the code works but the effects are not what I expect. I lookup people by their usderID, eg. d588588 which would indicate, let's say, a Doe, John. However, when I lookup an ID, Outlook finds me first person on the list whose last name starts with D, eg. Daniels, Joe. What I suppose happens is that by default the search is being done by names only, as in the screenshot. Tested this by entering the ID myself, and I get the same what macro gives me.

[Addressbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVoYm.jpg)

If I search with More Columns option enabled, I'm able to find the correct person. I've been trying to find a way to make my macro look in other fields, but no luck. I've looked all over the OOM but couldn't find anything that would help me.

Is there a way to make the macro look for the ID in other fields than the name only and get me the name of the person with this ID and not the person whose last name starts with the same letter as the the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` - GAL provider will be able to resolve by the login alias. Once you have the Recipient object, use `Recipient.Name` property

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that worked! Once I resolved the name from alias I was able to use the `AddressEntry` property because I've already had the exact full name. Had to apply one tweak though - I cannot resolve all names from GAL unfortunately, but made Outlook look for userIDs in  All Users address book by default. Many thanks!

Comment: Looping through all items in GAL can be extremely inefficient - some companies have tens of thousands of items there. Can Outlook resolve the alias if you type it in the To edit box in Outlook and hit Ctrl+K?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. However I usually check ca 150-200 names at each macro run so it runs quite OK (however macro tends to crash occassionally, I debug then, wait a couple of seconds and then continue - probably Exchange Server being busy and unresponsive). Answering you question - yes, no issues with resolving the alias, however I had to switch from GAL to All Users address book.